# how to get values from display tag to java code?

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

There is a jsp page where I put my name and this display column shows the occupant details.It shows occid, firstname etc. The prob is that I want to use this occid in toggle1(occid) and toggle2 but cant seem to use it. Is there any wait to access the occid from display column in toggle1 and toggle2? It will be of great help.

```
 <display:table name="sessionScope.List" pagesize="2"
                               export="true" sort="list">  

                    <display:column  property="occid" title=" Occupant ID" style="text-align:center;" ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="firstName" title="First Name" style="text-align:center;" ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="lastName" title="Last Name" style="text-align:center;"  ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="sonOf" title="Father's Name" style="text-align:center;"  ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="district" title="District" style="text-align:center;"  ></display:column>
                    <display:column  property="village" title="Village"  style="text-align:center;" ></display:column>

                    <display:column  title="Reservation Form" style="text-align:center;">
                        <a href="javascript:toggle1('${occid}')">
                            Show reservation details
                        </a>
                    </display:column>

                    <display:column  title="Agreement Form" style="text-align:center;">
                        <a href="javascript:toggle2('${occid}')">
                            Show agreement details
                        </a>
                    </display:column>
```

And this is the toggle javascript code.

```
function toggle1(occid)
{
alert(1);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getReservationDetails",
    data: "occid="+occid,              
    success: function(data){
        document.getElementById("resdet").innerHTML = data;   
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is it okay now?

Comment: Why do you need occid in java code. Seems like you need it in javascript ! What are you trying to do with toggle method. Can you post javascript code for toggle !!

Comment: with the occid in toggle1 it will another display tag which will have the reservation details of the person with same occid.

Comment: @AndrewThompson any advices??

Comment: Can you try making these changes and see if that works.
<display:table name="sessionScope.List" pagesize="2"
                               export="true" sort="list" id="itemName">

a href="javascript:toggle1('${itemName.occid}')">

Comment: @Divyang does that work for you ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31534/discussion-between-prp-and-divyang)

Comment: @Divyang Can you accept answer if that is what you were expecting for your question

Answer (score 1):

add id with display:table as this

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.List" pagesize="2" export="true" sort="list" id="itemName">
```

and within display:column use varialbe itemName.occid as this

```
<a href="javascript:toggle1('${itemName.occid}')">
```